# How can I write an interface with a function inside?

Tags: android, interface

I want to write an **interface** function who have a define function inside it.
I mean something like **onBackPress** who have "**super.onBackPress()**" inside it when we declare.

like this as shown in the below code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: thats interface or abstract class?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira i need both of them if it possible.

Comment: In interface you can have only collection of Abstract clases.

Comment: @Kesh1234 may you explain more in an **example**?

Comment: Interfaces can't have implementation. Your only options are to use java8 or scala.

Comment: onBackPressed() is public method which is define in super class and which is available for overriding to all child class who extend super class.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example, suppose you have three blog readers who reads blogs from different websites. Each one of them write their own methods to read the blogs from the website. As shown below:

Blog reader 1 may write the methods as:

```
readStream(), getString(), extractData().
```

Blog reader 2 may write the methods as :

```
connect(), toString(), extract().
```

Blog reader 3 may write the methods as :

```
getStream(), convertToString(), getBlogData().
```

So you will have to go through 6 methods. For this you will create an interface like BlogReader and tell the blog readers to implement this interface. You will have abstract methods like :

`getStream(), getString(), getBlogData()` and all the three readers will use same methods for he operation but they may write their logic in a different way. This is what interface means.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I know about **Interface** and **Abstract**.

my question is:
when you write onResume or onBackPress, at first they have a class like `super.onResume();`. i want to understand how it possible?

Comment: All the life cycle methods will have line like super.onResume(). This is nothing calling the parent class in the child or sub class.

Comment: It mean i can not use something like this in my code?